# Buscar palabra parecida en una sentencia MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Bueno pues tengo una tabla de vehículos y tengo el registro que se llama landroad.
Pues al hacer un `SELECT * FROM VEHICULOS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE ='%landroad%'` funciona.

Lo que busco es que me aparezca un resultado aunque el usuario haya escrito mal el nombre, y que si la sentencia encuentra una similitud, la muestre. En pocas palabras busco que

```
SELECT * FROM VEHICULOS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE = '%ladroad%'
```

devuelva el mismo resultado que la consulta de arriba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es posible pero para mi sería muy difícil y tedioso ponerte un ejemplo.

Hay algo que se llama "[distancia de levenshtein](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distancia_de_Levenshtein)" que es una distancia que evalúa el mínimo de operaciones necesarias para transformar de una palabra en otra. Entonces, la palabra con la distancia mínima sería la que sería buscada en su lugar... es muy tedioso en SQL.

Y [aquí](https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/) hay una implementación en SQL.

Tal vez algo que te pueda ser "útil", y más "fácil" de implementar, sea una tabla de "palabras/términos semejantes".

Comment: gracias!, he aprendido algo nuevo :D

Answer (score 0):

Da más opciones a tu búsqueda.- 
Ej.:

Que comience o contenga
LIKE = '%lad%'

O si sabes que existe otra nombre cual lo pueden buscar
LIKE = '%landroad%' or '%carretera%'